# Searching text with closing bracket vim

Tags: vim

I have a file with the following content:

```
<html>html
```

How can I use vim to search and select **just** `<html>`?  If I search:

```
/\<html\>
```

It selects all `html` (both in `<html>` and in `html`), but not `<html>` alone.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Vim syntax, but why do you have that opening `/`?

Comment: @Jonathan: that's how you instantiate a search in Vim

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply want:

```
/<html>
```

Your `\<` and `\>` are used when searching to delimit a word so, with your solution, both `html` occurrences are found, since they are separated by a 'non-word' character (`>`).